# Write the parabola equation of the height of a cable of a suspension bridge

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I need help with verifying this problem. Sorry for the poor quality of the image. It was provided with low quality.

Write the equation of the parabola to find the height of a cable above the ground at a distance of 250 m from the base of the mooring tower. The cable resists a load of equal weight at equal horizontal distances.[image]

This is what I did:

$$y=ax^2$$
$$100=a(500)^2$$
$$100=a(250,000)$$
$$\frac{100}{250,000}=\frac{a(250,000)}{250,000}$$
$$\frac{1}{2,500}=a$$

Then, the equation is

$$y=ax^2$$
$$y=\frac{1}{2,500}x^2$$

I would appreciate knowing if it's right or wrong. If wrong, what's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Now you need to substitute $x = 250$ metres to find the height of the cable there, which is just:

$$y = \frac{1}{2500}(250)^2 = 25$$

This answer makes sense as it is in between $0$ and $100$, which are the heights of the parabola at $x = 0$ and $x = 500$ respectively.

Comment: then the vertex of the parabola is $(0,250)$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Something is not making sense to me. How the vertex is $(0,250)$ and there are points higher than the vertex that are $(-500,100)$ and $(500,100)$. I tried it using the formula in my textbook $(x-h)^2=4a(y-k)^2$.

Comment: Then I substituted in $x$ $500$ and in $y$ $100$ and in $h$ $0$ and in $k$ $250$. I get that $a$ is $\frac{25}{9}$ and that the equation is $x^2=\frac{100}{9}(y-250)^2$. When I graph in desmos.com is super weird. Is not a parabola.

Comment: @gi2302 Is the $250$ metres referring to $250$ metres right from the base of the mooring tower?

Comment: the 250m is what is not making any sense to me. I don't think the vertex is $(0,250)$. I think that the $250$ is referring to the distance between the origin to the base of the tower. I would make sense that because the point of the base of the right tower is (500,00).

Comment: Thanks for confirming this; I have now updated my answer.